# How zoom the background-image in while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

This is my code in html, css and js (very simplified):

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="first">
            <div class="background"></div>
            <div class="videoBackground"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="titleGFS" class="title">Ipse eorum</div>
                <div id="txt1" class="text">Ipse eorum opinionibus accedo, qui Germaniae...</div>
                <div id="txt2" class="text">Personalmente inclino verso l'opinione di quanti ritengono che i popoli della Germania...</div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- other sections -->

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    html,body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    } 

    #wrapper{
        min-width: 1000px;
    }

    section{
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    #first{
        color: whitesmoke;
        background: url('1.jpg') no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;   
    }

    #first .background{
        background-image: none;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

JS:

```
/*Change background (I need it in this way)*/
$('#first').css({background:'none'});
$('#first .background').css({backgroundImage: "url('1.jpg')"});

/*Scrolling*/
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $maxScroll=300;
    var $maxScale=1.3;
    var $x=$(window).scrollTop()/1000+1;
    if($(window).scrollTop()>$maxScroll) $x=$maxScale;
    $('#first .background').css({transform: 'scale('+$x+','+$x+')'});
```

**What I want to do:** zoom in the background-image with a limit of scaling of 1.3 while the page is scrolling down, the background must be remained in fixed position.

It works: I mean, when I scroll a little the background zooms in, ok!, then it starts to scroll down... I can't understand why and I tried to find an explanation by searching everywhere.

Comment: What does this `$('#first .background').css({transform: 'scale('+$x+','+$x+')'});` tell you ?

Comment: I edited this post because I have forgotten to specify that I want to realise the zoom effect while scrolling the page. Sorry.

Comment: so does my answer actually answer your question ?

Comment: No, because the problem I explained remains. With a little scroll the background zooms out, but with more scroll the background scrolls down! Why?

Comment: @Alp I'm so sorry, when I read my question I noticed confusions with words to make misunderstanding and I updated it with more details _(I work too much...)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your scroll method, you play with background with this line:

```
 $('#first .background').css({transform: 'scale('+$x+','+$x+')'});
```

It **transforms** background, i.e. scales it. Comment out or play with other transformations to see the difference. If you don't need it, remove that line altogether.

**__UPDATE__**

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xn06vvd/). I Changed the image URL as follows:

```
$('#first').css({background:'none'});

/*Scrolling*/
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $maxScroll=500;
    var $maxScale=1.3;
    var $x=$(window).scrollTop()/100+1;
    console.log("scrollTop : " + $(window).scrollTop() + "- x : " + $x);
    if($(window).scrollTop()>$maxScroll) $x=$maxScale;
//    $('#first .background').css({transform: 'scale('+$x+','+$x+')'});

        $('#first .background').css({transform: 'scale('+$x+','+$x+')'});

});
```

I also changed 1000 to 100 in the line below:

```
var $x=$(window).scrollTop()/100+1;
```

This way, I made the division ($x) greater in value and it helped scaling to be more obvious.

Let me try to explain what happens in your case: scaling is so minimal that you hit the barrier too soon scaling stops.

In my case tho, keep an eye on console, scaling range is larger, so I keep scale the image more and more. But after I exceed 500 limit, image is zoomed out because of the following line:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>$maxScroll) $x=$maxScale;
```

where $x is reset to $maxScale (Zoom out) and if I keep scrolling, it starts zooming in again.

Does it make sense now ?